# MATLAB: Not enough input arguments error given

Tags: matlab

I am given the error

> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in fun (line 2) f = cos(2*x)./exp(x);

When trying to run my code with the command

> simp(fun, 0, 2*pi, 120)

for my code

```
function I = simp(fun, a,b,n)

%Standard simpson's rule 
tol = 0.0001;

h = (b-a)/(2*n); % The subinterval spacing
x = a:h:b; % The partition points
y = fun(x); % The function values at those points
i = 0:2*n; % Makes a list from 0 to 2*n

coeffs = 3+(-1).^(i+1); % Makes a list of 2s and 4s to use in the Simpson's Rule
coeffs(1) = 1; coeffs(end)=1;

SR = h/3 * sum(coeffs .* y); % This is the Simpson's Rule
disp(SR);
```

---

```
function f = fun(x)
f = cos(2*x)./exp(x);
end
```

The error is telling me that I did not provide enough input arguments, but I see that I give the function (fun), 'a', 'b', and 'n' values. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function handle with `@`:

```
simp(@fun, 0, 2*pi, 120)
```

You can also use:

```
simp(@(x) cos(2*x)./exp(x), 0, 2*pi, 120)
```

When you use only `fun`, Matlab think you try to call the function with no parameter. `@fun` is the actual function.

Comment: Hi Twisted, thank you for the answer. Why must I use the anonymous function handle?

Comment: Function handle let you do things like: `f = @myfunction`, or `f = @(x) anotherfunction(x)`.

Comment: Hm, okay. I'll just have to read more documentation regarding it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: it's just a reference to the function instead of the actual function :) Take a look at this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html

Comment: @Taln : `fun` is the same as `fun()`. `@fun` is a function handle to `fun`. It’s not an anonymous function. An anonymous function would be the second case (`@(x)...`), where you define a new function without a name and get its handle.